# When using Relationalize in Glue there is no id in root table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a `DynamicFrame` in `Glue` and I am using the `Relationalize` method which creates me 3 new dynamic frames; `root_table`, `root_table_1` and `root_table_2`.

When I print the Schema of the tables or after I inserted the tables in database I noticed that in the `root_table` the id is missing so I cannot make joins between the `root_table` and other tables.

I tried all the possible combinations.

Is there something i missing?

```
    datasource1 = Relationalize.apply(frame = renameId, name = "root_ds", transformation_ctx = "datasource1")
print(datasource1.keys())
print(datasource1.values())
for df_name in datasource1.keys():
    m_df = datasource1.select(df_name)
    print "Writing to Redshift table: ", df_name
    m_df.printSchema()

    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = m_df, catalog_connection = "Redshift", connection_options = {"database" : "redshift", "dbtable" : df_name}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "df_to_db")
```

Comment: can you please paste the sample data and the whole code here?

Comment: I paste the data as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the code below (removing the import bits) on your data and got wrote into S3. I got two files as pasted after the code. I am reading from the glue catalog after running the crawler on your data.

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sampledb", table_name = "json_aws_glue_relationalize_stackoverflow", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

dfc = datasource0.relationalize("advertise_root", "s3://aws-glue-temporary-009551040880-ap-southeast-2/")

for df_name in dfc.keys():
    m_df = dfc.select(df_name)
    print "Writing to S3 file: ", df_name
    datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = m_df, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://aws-glue-relationalize-stackoverflow/" + df_name +"/"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

job.commit()
```

main table
advertiserCountry,advertiserId,amendReason,amended,clickDate,clickDevice,clickRefs.clickRef2,clickRefs.clickRef6,commissionAmount.amount,"commissionAmount.currency","commissionSharingPublisherId",commissionStatus,customParameters,customerCountry,declineReason,id,ipHash,lapseTime,oldCommissionAmount,oldSaleAmount,orderRef,originalSaleAmount,paidToPublisher,paymentId,publisherId,publisherUrl,saleAmount.amount,saleAmount.currency,siteName,transactionDate,transactionDevice,transactionParts,transactionQueryId,type,url,validationDate,voucherCode,voucherCodeUsed,partition_0
AT,123456,,false,2018-09-05T16:31:00,iPhone,"asdsdedrfrgthyjukiloujhrdf45654565423212",www.website.at,1.5,EUR,,pending,,AT,,321547896,-27670654789123380,68,,,,,false,0,654987,,1.0,EUR,https://www.site.at,2018-09-05T16:32:00,iPhone,1,0,Lead,https://www.website.at,,,false,advertise

Another table for transaction parts
id,index,"transactionParts.val.amount","transactionParts.val.commissionAmount","transactionParts.val.commissionGroupCode","transactionParts.val.commissionGroupId","transactionParts.val.commissionGroupName"
1,0,1.0,1.5,LEAD,654654,Lead

Glue generated primary key column named "transactionParts" in the base table and the id in the transactionparts table is the foreign key to that column. As you can see it preserved, the original id column as it is.

Can you please try the code on your data and see if it works (changing the source table name as per yours)? Try to write to S3 as CSV  first to figure out if thats working. Please let me know your findings.

Comment: I dont know how i missed it. i was expecting column name id and only id and didn't even see at the other columns. The documentation says column should be id and I was just following it. Thanks a lot.